# How to protect inner tube on wider rims?

Tags: rims, innertube, protection

If you take a look at for example Schwalbe offering you will notice that the max rim tape width for 28" rims is 25mm. So how to protect inner tube on wider rims? Could tubeless rim tape be a substitute here?

*Please note protection has to be twofold -- against pressure and wheel imperfections.*

Comment: Sorry if i'm being stupid, but is this question about rim tape?

Comment: @AndyP, yes, my question was originally not clear. The problem is the rims are wider than rim tapes (rim tapes for inner tubes), so what to do then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For band-type rim strips or traditional cotton tape etc, there is not a strict corollary between rim internal width and width of the strip. It just needs to sit in place properly while reliably covering all the spoke holes. For example, I frequently use basic repair 18mm vinyl rim strips that are nomimally "29er" but work more often than not on most 700C hybrid and wide road rims as well as most non-tubeless 29er rims, so basically on 622 rims whose internal widths are in the range of 18mm to 23mm or so.

There are some non-tubeless rims where due to wide spacing of the spoke holes, historically the only good option was the wider sizes of traditional tape, like 22mm Velox.

For all tubeless-compatible rims, just going to tubeless tape is an acceptable choice and might be the best one since it bulks things up the least. Use at least two layers if it's going to be a higher pressure application. You could use it on many non-tubeless rims, but it has limits to how well it works with deep channels without curling on to itself during application, so it may not always work.